# Binding redirect not working for System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, binding, prism

Currently using PRISM5 which has a dependency on Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition which also seems to have a dependency on System.Windows.Forms 2.0.0.0, as when I run the compiled application I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

I updated the app.config file to include the bindingredirect:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I have .net 4.5, 4.0 and 3.5 installed, however not .NET 2.0 runtime. Is there any reason why the redirect is not working?

Full stack trace as requested:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.<>c__DisplayClassf.<GetNotAllreadyLoadedModuleInfos>b__b(FileInfo file)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetModuleInfos(String path)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetModuleInfos(String path)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerLoad()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.Load()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
   at Ninject.Extension.Prism.NinjectBootstrapper.InitializeModules() in c:\Users\seth_000\Documents\Projects\dars-sdk\Ninject.Extension.Prism-3.0.0.1\NinjectBootstrapper.cs:line 169
   at Ninject.Extension.Prism.NinjectBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration) in c:\Users\seth_000\Documents\Projects\dars-sdk\Ninject.Extension.Prism-3.0.0.1\NinjectBootstrapper.cs:line 94
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Bootstrapper.Run()
   at Dars.UI.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in c:\Users\seth_000\Documents\Projects\dars-sdk\dars\Dars.UI\App.xaml.cs:line 22
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Dars.UI.App.Main() in c:\Users\seth_000\Documents\Projects\dars-sdk\dars\Dars.UI\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 51
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? PRISM uses `System.Resources.ResXResourceReader` that comes from `System.Windows.Forms`, but all references point to `System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`.

Comment: It seems that your `DirectoryModuleCatalog` finds and tries to load an assembly that has a reference to a .NET 2.0 assembly. Inspect your scanned folder, there might be some "orphaned" assemblies which you don't use anymore. Or, you could adopt the config file of that assemby providing a binding redirection.